# Where to find source data for incubation/onset/duration time of reported US cases Salmonella food poisoning?

Tags: data-request, medical, food, disease

I would like to be able to create a histogram showing the onset of illness and duration of symptoms reported within the USA for *Salmonella enterica* infections (or some other common foodborne illness). I am able to find published information from reputable sources like [this](http://www.fda.gov/Food/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/ucm103263.htm) that simply declares what the known onset time (6-48 hours) and duration (4-7 days) of the illness is, but I can't find actual source data on this.

I should clarify that I'm not interested in identifying information about reported cases, just the raw numbers of those individual cases. I want to be able to either confirm or refute the blanket declarations about onset time and duration of an illness that are found all over the web (and don't always match up).

The CDC has made available [this](http://wwwn.cdc.gov/foodborneoutbreaks/) database which appears to be compiled from individual hospitalizations (I can see where the person recording the info would choose the option `other - please describe in remarks` but no remarks are included in the data), but this particular dataset lacks any information regarding the timing of the illness.

I've contacted the CDC and the FDA for assistance but I have not yet heard back. I'll update this if and when I get an answer from them that might resolve this question.

Is there an already public source of this information available on the web? Or, if not, what organization would be best to contact for this info?

Is this the kind of dataset that is a good candidate to be acquired through a Freedom of Information Law (FOIL) request?